# How to save my app's settings?

Tags: java, android, absolutelayout

How do I save the back ground setting in the app and when it exits back it still saves that background
As the default app I to be :

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg2"
android:id="@+id/bgplayer">
```

and click button

```
 bgplayer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg1a);
```

If you want to completely exit the app and re-enter the background it will be bga1

Comment: Use sharedPreference to save your choice....

Comment: This is very Bad coding practices. Don;t use that classes which has been deprecated. Ask your doubt with your effort.

Comment: here's a link on how to use shared preferences https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use shared preferences in Activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

then save like this:

```
prefs.edit().putInt("your_key", R.drawable.bg1a).apply();
```

and read like this:

```
int value = prefs.getInt("your_key", defaultIntValue);
```

And set background as:

```
bgplayer.setBackgroundResource(value);
```

Comment: I can not complete a complete code you can do a template to help me, if so then thank you

Comment: Where are you using this code? In Activity, Fragment?

Comment: Not really sure my answer is correct, but I wrote it in onCreate

Comment: put your class with on Create method

Comment: put your all class

Comment: MainActivity.java Player.java NotificationClick.java